# Unable to get DatePicker work after selecting on a text input field of a HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date, datepicker

I have a HTML edit form that shows fields from database and allow users to edit the database fields. For one of the fields which is known as "detentiondate", I plan to put a date picker. So that when clicked to edit the date, a datepicker will be shown and I can retrieve the new date and update to the database. My date format is in mm/dd/yyyy (e.g. 01/28/2016).

Now I have trouble getting the datepicker to show up once I click on the textfield. Here is my code and please let me know where have I went wrong, thank you!

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {     
     $('#selectDate').datepicker({
     dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
     onSelect: function(dateEdit, inst) {

       if (dateEdit.trim().length != 0) {      
                var dateSelected = new Object();
                dateSelected.latedate = dateEdit;                        
            } 
    }
});

});
</script>

<input id="selectDate" type="text" name="detentiondate<?php echo $StudLateDetails['lateid'] ?>" size="15" value="<?php echo $StudLateDetails['detentiondate'] ?>"/>

//This is gotten from the page source which shows the database field values
<input id="selectDate" type="text" name="detentiondate21" size="15" value="01/28/2016"/></tr>
```

Comment: Datepicket not picking the date or database field issue?

Comment: It works fine here - https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/qaw0Lbsn/

Comment: this code "<input id="selectDate" type="text" name="detentiondate<?php echo $StudLateDetails['lateid'] ?>" size="15" value="<?php echo $StudLateDetails['detentiondate'] ?>"/>"

Runs in Loop ?

Comment: @devpro no issue with database field, just that datepicker doesn't want to show up

Comment: @NikolayErmakov that's funny, and it is exactly what I want it to look like! But it's not showing up, it is because my php values runs in a loop?

Comment: @VadivelS Yes! It runs in a loop!

Comment: ok me add answer see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok You Add class name in textbox like this

you change Script include line this order

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {     
 $('.selectDate').datepicker({
 dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
 onSelect: function(dateEdit, inst) {

   if (dateEdit.trim().length != 0) {      
            var dateSelected = new Object();
            dateSelected.latedate = dateEdit;                        
        } 
}
});

});</script>

<input id="selectDate<?php echo $StudLateDetails['lateid'] ?>" class="selectDate" type="text" name="detentiondate<?php echo $StudLateDetails['lateid'] ?>" size="15" value="<?php echo $StudLateDetails['detentiondate'] ?>"/>
```

This code Working fine

Comment: I've immediately went to try that but unfortunately it still stays the same. I clearly understood that the purpose your code is to give the selectDate a unique id value. Do you want to visit this website to take a look? That is the page that I'm working on and trying to get the detentiondate text field to have a datepicker: http://ats2.thetechplorer.com/FYPATS/editStudentLD.php/?nric=S9531159H

Comment: jQuery was included twice  . so remove one and test

Comment: So sorry to trouble you.. Tried removing each jQuery and test, it appears to have no effect on it.

Comment: if you have  teamviewer  ? send me userid and PWD to vadiveljobs@gmail.com

Comment: Yes i have and i just dropped you a mail

Comment: Oh my god!! I changed the script lines to your order and it worked! Thank you so much! I guess what's left is to change the calendar css :) Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Add this Two lines on Calendar CSS Done

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.min.css">

Comment: Are the two lines to replace my "<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"> ?

Comment: No. not  replace  your style.css file

Comment: Okay! Got it, I'm so grateful for your help! Thank you!

Comment: I think I do not have enough reputation to do it. But will definitely do so once I have enough!!